# iOS Foundation: system font size

Tags: objective-c, ios, uifont

I would like to know if systemFontSize in iOS app tableView is **always** the same for textLabel? This is are depening to style?

For example when I  `NSLog(@"%f",[UIFont systemFontSize]);` I'm getting 14.0. Is this are always the same?

And what's more: How can i change font size without changing the font-family (assuming that i have my own fonts in my plist).

I tried:

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Sansation-Light" size:12.0];
```

But UIFont always want for me fontname/family. How can i avoid that and have one font to all my screen and changing only size?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

System Fonts are describe as following :

```
+ (CGFloat)labelFontSize;//Returns the standard font size used for labels.
+ (CGFloat)buttonFontSize;//Returns the standard font size used for buttons.
+ (CGFloat)smallSystemFontSize;//Returns the size of the standard small system font.
+ (CGFloat)systemFontSize;//Returns the size of the standard system font.
```

and you can change the font size without the font family like this :

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
```

Comment: There are new options available since iOS 7, like `[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]` also a notification `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` to monitor the systems wide font changes.

Answer (score 2):

System font sizes are not always the same. Beginning in iOS 7 there is [`Dynamic Type`](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/supporting-dynamic-type/). Users can set their preferred font size in the system settings. This is the recommended way for apps to get and set their font sizes now.

In the Interface Builder you can choose things like `Body` or `Title 1` under the Font settings. The actual size will be adjusted according to the user's system settings. Programmatically you use `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: )`. See [this post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/auto-adjusting-fonts-for-dynamic-type/) for more details about doing this in iOS 10 and Swift 3.

See also

- [Typography docs](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/)
- [Text Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW65)

Comment: @AdilSoomro, I couldn't find a good documentation replacement link but I did replace all the links with better ones. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the above answer. The above methods are members of UIFont class. So to get the default button font size...

```
float defaultFontSize = [UIFont buttonFontSize];
```