# iOS Change system font to custom font globally

Tags: ios, objective-c, customization, uifont

I want to change all system font to custom font at one place with storyboard and xib.

I have tried below code to change font.

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:17.0]];
[[UITextField appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:17.0]];
```

When I used above code its working fine but its changing size also.

I just want to change font family and keep size as it has in storyboard or xib.

Please provide me some good solution.

Comment: U can get help from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730658/change-default-font-to-custom-fonts-in-whole-app

Answer (score 0):

I think you can keep using the same statements, but instead of setting the size using a literal of your choice, just use the current system font size like this:

```
float currentSystemFontSize = [UIFont systemFontSize];
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:currentSystemFontSize]];
```

This should keep the system's font size and only change the font family.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484369/4763963) answer for more information about how to get system font size. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

call below methods in ViewDidLoad():

```
[self setCustomFontFamilyNotSize:@"CustomFontName" forView:self.view andSubViews:YES];
```

Method Dealarations:

```
-(void)setCustomFontFamilyNotSize:(NSString*)customFontFamily forView:(UIView*)view andSubViews:(BOOL)isSubViews
{
 if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
 {
     UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)view;
     [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:customFontFamily size:[[lbl font] pointSize]]];
 }

 if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
 {
     UITextField *txt = (UITextField *)view;
     [txt setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:customFontFamily size:[[txt font] pointSize]]];
 }   
}
```